# Android Going between Views

Tags: android, button, view, android-intent, back

In my app, I will occassionally go to an activity and when I click the back button on the phone, it will take me back to a completely different activity than the one I was previously on.  For example, I have 2 main activities and one preferences activity.  My action to go to any activity is as simple as this:

```
Intent loadmainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(loadmainIntent);
```

If my app starts at View1 and I go to the preferences view, sometimes when I select the back button it will take me to View2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling finish()

Comment: I was really happy about the last question that got answered, yet I searched the page for 5 minutes looking for a way to reward the user.  There is no where to click to do such a thing.  I must be blind.

Comment: Since you accepted the answer below, I'm assuming you found how to do it? :)  Note:  you can still go back to your older questions and accept the ones that are appropriate to be accepted.  Just click your name ([Jesse](http://stackoverflow.com/users/679439/jesse)) at the top of the page.

Comment: I did go back and most of them were answered correctly outside of the ANSWER section.  Just like your comments above, there is no CHECK button.  So Matt above said "are you calling Finish()" and if that was the best answer, how would i choose that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml file for [`android:launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).  Further described in [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Comment: Thanks,  I think that fixed it.  I had one of my launch modes to SingleInstance and it needed to be SingleTop.